# MVC dropdown / HTML Select selected item to model

Tags: model-view-controller, html-select, html.dropdownlistfor

Trying to use HTML.Select in place of dropdown.for because for some reason the model is reporting as bring null. (That is not the main issue but I would like to know the reason for that) The issue concerning me is that because I am using a standard html select control, the view cannot associate the selected item value to a model property.

View is as follows:

```
@model CustomerPortal.ViewModels.Interfaces.ICustomerEmailViewModel

@{
 ViewBag.Title = "Create";
 Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<script>
var customerId;
var emailTypeId;
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()


<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>CustomerEmailViewModel</h4>
    <hr/>
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})


    <div style="clear: both">
        <div style="float: left">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerId, new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
        </div>
        <div style="float: left;">
            <select id="Customer_Id" name=" Customer" onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;"></select>
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CustomerId, new {id = "hdnCustomerId"})
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>

    <div style="clear: both">
        <div>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAddress, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailAddress, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress, "", new {@class = "text-danger"})
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>


    <div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document)
        .ready(function() {

            customerId = $('#Customer_Id').val();
            emailTypeId = $('#CustomerEmailType_Id').val();

            $.getJSON('/api/CustomerEmailTypeApi/GetAllCustomerEmailTypes/',
                function(data) {
                    var items = '';

                    $.each(data,
                        function(i, emailType) {
                            items += "<option value='" + emailType.Value + "'>" + emailType.Text + "</option>";
                        });
                    $('#CustomerEmailType_Id').html(items);
                });

            $.getJSON('/api/CustomerApi/GetAllCustomers/',
                function(data) {
                    var items = '';

                    $.each(data,
                        function(i, customer) {
                            items += "<option value='" + customer.value +     "'>" + customer.Text + "</option>";
                        });
                    $('#Customer_Id').html(items);
                });
        });

</script>
```

The controller:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Create(CustomerEmailViewModel customerEmail)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            CustomerEmail cevm = new CustomerEmail
            {
                Id = customerEmail.Id,
                EmailAddress = customerEmail.EmailAddress,
                CustomerId = customerEmail.CustomerId,
                CustomerEmailTypeId = customerEmail.CustomerEmailType.Id
            };

            try
            {
                _portalUow.CustomerEmailRepository.Insert(cevm);
                _portalUow.Save();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Danger("An exception occured while updating the database.  The transaction was rolled back");
                return null; // System.Web.UI.WebControls.View(customer);
            }


            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(customerEmail);
    }
```

Thank you for any help with this....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use @Html.DropDownListFor

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.property, new SelectList(Model.dropdownlist, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control" })
```

In controller you will need to assign the value of dropdownlist to Model.dropdownlist too. For example:

```
var list = new SelectList(new[]
        {
            new {ID="CustomerId1", Name="CustomerId1" },
            new {ID="CustomerId2", Name="CustomerId2" },               
        }, "ID", "Name", 1
        );
        your list instance = list;
```

Comment: Thank you Shawn... not exactly the answer, but you set me on the instantiation path which solved the problem... I hadn't instantiated the model in the controller... Not being careful here!

Comment: Still there Shawn? The problem has progressed... I am trying to return to this view from a view that was launched from here. So I have two select lists on this page which pass url params to the page they launch.. I don't know the models being used when this page loads, hence using the selects with no selected values at page load. But on this view page when they choose the options to launch the target view, do things then come back here, and still have the selected option showing The question is, how can I get the same values in the select list to be selected after the view has loaded?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have 2 views and you want to pass the selected list item on first view to second view?

Comment: nearly. Yes, there are 2 views. The first view has no model associated with it. The options are in loaded with a default 'choose an option' value selected. The second view is loaded with a model (could be one of many) based on the options chosen in the first. The second view is working perfectly. It lets the user add an item associated with the option chosen in the first view. View 2 has dropdowns like view 1 which can be changed. What needs to happen is when the action in the 2nd view is complete, the actionresult takes the user back to view 1 but passes the selected options back to the view.

Comment: You can use TempData to pass back selected options back to view 1.[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476967/WhatplusisplusViewData-cplusViewBagplusandplusTem) is a link that will explain how to do it, plus will tell you how does it differentiates itself from ViewBag or ViewData.

Comment: Thank you for coming back... I tried to use TempData, but  the code fails to build the view with the message that ...MVC.TempDataDictionary does not containing definition for the model could not be found (maybe missing a reference)

Comment: Hi @GarethC I think it's best to post your problem to another post as someone better than me can answer to your question. Somemore, it can help others people aswell.